# Special case of limsup inequality

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

If you are given two sequences $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ such that $a_{n}b_{n} \geq 0$ and the limits $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_{n} = a$ and $\lim\limits_{b \rightarrow \infty}b_{n} = b$ then can it be shown that $$\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(-a_{n}b_{n}) \leq -ab$$

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably assuming too much. If $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$, then $-a_n b_n \to -ab$. Thus $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} (-a_nb_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}(-a_nb_n) = -ab.$$

Comment: I was just about to post this!

Comment: @UmbertoP. Oh yeah of course, thanks.